# After Decompiling Apk file, I get numbers instead of constants. How can I get The string values of those numbers?

Tags: java, android, apk, decompiler

Sadly I have lost my source code of an app I had uploaded to the store. Using this site to decompile the java code: 
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

I get something like this in the layout xml for example:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@ref/0x7f060000"
    android:background="rgb8(0xffffffff)"
    android:layout_width="-1"
    android:layout_height="dimension(1)"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_weight="1065353216.000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="1"
    android:id="@ref/0x7f060001"
    android:background="rgb8(0xffffffff)"
    android:layout_width="-1"
    android:layout_height="-1">

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@ref/0x7f060002"
    android:background="rgb8(0xffffffff)"
    style="@style/GenericProgressBackground">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="-2"
        android:layout_height="-2"
        style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I translate the numbers back to the constants I had in the original code?

Comment: Do you mean the `id`?

Comment: All the numbers you see there were originally constant variable names.

Comment: the decompiled code will have an R file. it will have all the references. And one small suggestion, if you can decompile your code, any else could. where is security to your code?

Comment: I know, but I don't mind it. The app is free anyway. Also in client side web applications, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I don't see any R file. what folder is it in?

Comment: I found a  duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082661/setcontentview-shows-number-how-can-i-find-layout-after-decompile-code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used apktools as I read in another duplicate and it did work better for the xml files.

[Extracting Android .apk and reading contents of XML file in res/layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868768/extracting-android-apk-and-reading-contents-of-xml-file-in-res-layout)

Comment: Actually I also found out  there was also a public.xml file with all the numbers and their equivalent names